# Flutter - Crashlytics still loading in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

I'm trying to implement Crashlytics for my Flutter Application.

I followed this [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/overview/) to implement Crashlytics but it still loading in Firebase:

[image]

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
}
```

**And when I press my button:**

```
child: FloatingActionButton(
  heroTag: "mainFloatingButtonTag",
  onPressed: () {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();     
  },
  ...
)
```

Crashed my app 10-15 times and still nothing. I don't know if I have forget something. (Tested in Debug Mode and Release Mode)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is currently under investigation.

Please see the discussion at https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3669

Updated instructions can found here https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/3860

Answer (score -1):

The report will be sent to console only when
`FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);`

[Here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/usage) is how to implement it with firebase_crashlytics.
*Hope it helps!*